# how to plot a bar for a variable according to specific value of another variable

Tags: r

I have a problem with plotting issue. I want to plot a bar that indicates the percentage of each day of a week when the "time" variable is equal to "Dinner". could you please help me.
any little help will be greatly appreciated.

```
> library(ggplot2)
> #sample data
> head(tips,3)
  total_bill tip    sex smoker day   time size
1         17 1.0 Female     No Sun Dinner    2
2         10 1.7   Male     No Sun Dinner    3
3         21 3.5   Male     No Sun Dinner    3
```

Comment: Have you tried to do a plot yet?

Answer (score 0):

Using `count` function to count number of occurrences day-wise and `barplot` function to plot

```
#generating sample dataframe
tips <- data.frame(total_bills=1:10, tip=10:19, sex=sample(c("male","female"),10, replace = TRUE), smoker=sample(c("yes","no"),10, replace = TRUE), day = sample(c("Mon","Tue","Wed","Fri","Sat","Sun"),10, replace = TRUE),time=sample(c("Breakfast","Lunch","Dinner"),10, replace = TRUE),size = sample(1:5,10, replace = TRUE), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

#count the number of occurences using _count_ function
io <- plyr::count(tips[tips$time == "Dinner",], vars = "day")

#getting days percentage
io$count_percent <- round(io$freq/sum(io$freq) * 100,2)

> io
day freq count_percent
1 Sun    1            20
2 Tue    2            40
3 Wed    2            40

#generate barplot
require(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(io, aes(day, count_percent))
p + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

Sample Output for the above data :

[image: snap1]

Comment: how about using ggplot2 package : ggplot()+geom_bar()?

Comment: oops, i missed to paste `%` count code here, _wait_

Comment: @far thanks for suggestion, i updated it to `ggplot`